# Memory leak with dynamic allocation inside a function

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I am learning C++ in an online class, currently discussing pointers and memory leaks.

In the course it was told that when a function body ends all local variables are destroyed (in reverse order to which they were declared).

What i'm trying to understand is whether this code leaks memory or not:

```
void function()
{
    TestClass *p = new TestClass();
}
```

As it seems, it does, but i am not sure why the pointer "p" is not being dereferenced to its heap address and the data there is deleted once the function scope exits.

Comment: This function leaks, there's no `delete` call made for `p` and `p` isn't accessible anywhere outside the function. To achive the bahavior you described, use smart pointers. C++ has no automatic garbage collection.

Comment: OP is mixing up *the pointer* with *the thing pointed to*. In C++ there is no automatic "ownership" relation between a pointer and the thing pointed to, unlike some other languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely it will leak memory. **when a function body ends all local variables are destroyed** indicates to the variables that are created in stack, not heap. If you allocate memory in heap, you have to release it when done.

Another thing is your concept about *dereference* is wrong. **Dereference** means *using the object pointed by a pointer*, not freeing the memory of the pointer, which is called **Deallocation**

Comment: That was the way it was presented in the course. It was said that when you delete p, the pointer is dereferenced to its heap address and the object is deleted. I assumed the same would happen as it does for locals (on the stack).

Comment: @lysergic-acid, Pointer already contains the heap address, that is what pointer is for. No need to *dereference* to get the address. As said, *dereference* is done to access the **object** pointed by it.

Comment: you accurately said what i meant :)

Answer (score 1):

The pointer itself will be destroyed as it is allocated in stack, but the data which `p` points to will leak. If you write

```
TestClass tc;
TestClass *p = &tc;
```

then all the objects will be created in stack and destroyed, but using `new` forces to use the memory from heap. You have to use `delete` to release it.

Answer (score 0):

`new` is used to allocate memory for a C++ class object in heap, the object's constructor is called after the memory is allocated.

The `delete` operator must be used to deallocate the memory allocated with the new operator, otherwise there is a memory leak.

`delete *p;`